# Detect whether an iOS device has a home bar using JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, css, ios, progressive-web-apps

I am building a web app for iOS, and want to know if it's possible using JS or CSS to detect whether a device has the on-screen Home Bar at the bottom (i.e. an iPhone X, 11, or iPad Pro - with rounded corners and no home button).

Because if creating a tab bar, I need to know whether or not to add the additional padding at the bottom to accommodate this, as illustrated in the image below.

[image]

Short of using media queries to detect from a list of EXACT screen resolutions for these devices and hoping for the best, I can't come up with a solution.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: putting a pin in this. You need to account for the iOS 'safe' area and there are iOS specific media queries to use....need to look up things...

This might be the best article I know of at the moment on iPhone specific layout CSS
https://css-tricks.com/the-notch-and-css/

and here is Apple's article

https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/

Comment: and note, const was changed to env

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm struggling with this exact thing! This seems promising, but I can't get it to return anything by 0px: https://benfrain.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-phone-notches-environment-variables-env-in-javascript-from-css/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Working from [this post](https://benfrain.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-phone-notches-environment-variables-env-in-javascript-from-css/), I was able to calculate the height of the bottom safe area, thus determining whether the home bar is present. If you return a non-zero pixel value, the home bar is (probably) there. If it returns `0px`, no home bar.

Definitely read the linked post, but the general idea is that you'll set the [CSS `env()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env) to the `:root` element and then read the calculated value back.

**Here's how it works:**

First, you'll need to use the whole available screen by putting this in the `<head>` section of your document:

`<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover" />`

Then, add to your CSS:

```
:root {
    --sat: env(safe-area-inset-top);
    --sar: env(safe-area-inset-right);
    --sab: env(safe-area-inset-bottom); /* THIS ONE GETS US THE HOME BAR HEIGHT */
    --sal: env(safe-area-inset-left);
}
```

Finally, read back the value in Javascript:

`getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--sab")`

This should return a value like `34px` when the home bar is present and `0px` when it ain't.

Answer (score 0):

the webkit has a bug.

env(safe-area-inset-*) will be 0px when the first page load.

refer the bug report : https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=191872#c5